# Capitalizing last letter in Java using String methods

Tags: java, string, capitalize

how can i capitalize the last letter of a String? Is there a method in the String Class to do this?

I'm practicing with some exercise, and i was asked to do this with a method.

Comment: An idea might be to search for capitalizing the *first* letter. Then look what you have to modify.

Comment: Yeah, good idea! I'll check it, thank you!

Comment: Whoops, misread it as JavaScrupt

Comment: Your requirement is vague: do you mean capitalize the last character in the string (if that happens to be a letter), or find the last letter in the string and capitalize it. For instance, should `"az0"` remain as `"az0"`, or should it become `"aZ0"`?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. but you can write one yourself.

```
 public String capitalizeLastLetter(String word) {
    //null check
    int length = word.length();
    String capitalizedLetter = word.substring(length - 2, length - 1).toUppercase();
    return word.substring(0, length - 2) + capitalizedLetter;
}
```

Comment: Is this still a String  : String capitalizedLetter = word.substring(length - 2, length - 1).toUppercase();

Comment: Of course it is.. substring returns a string even if it's one letter

Comment: @Zildyan or zero letters. But you can do this more efficiently with `Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(length - 1))`, which avoids creating 2 strings.

Comment: True I didn' recall that..